# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando utilizar o module [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) porem no Mac OS 10.14, apresenta esse erro tanto ao tentar installar com o pip e com o easy_install apresenta o erro falando que ja existe o este module.Fiz um teste no windows e os comandos funcionaram corretamente, e instalei ele via pip direto no CMD, alguem poderia me ajudar?

instalacao com pip
[image: instalacao com pip]
instalacao com easy_install
[image: instalacao com easy_install]
instalacao no Windows 10 
[image: instalacao no Windows 10]

Vale resaltar que instalei o python 3.7.1 e a versao do pip 18.0

Comment: O ideal seria que vc colocasse os textos, com imagens é péssimo para visualizar.
Me parece q vc esta usando a distribuição original do python no seu SO, já tentou utilizar algum gerenciador de venvs? se não, tente o anaconda (ou o miniconda), certeza q seu problema será resolvido:
https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos

Comment: Eu acho a imagem melhor para ter o panorama completo, pra aumentar a imagem é só clicar nela. O anaconda nao cheguei a usar, utilizei o brew para instalar o pipenv e instalei com o pipenv, porem me parece que ele adiciona como se fosse o projeto, porem preciso que o module seja global vou usar em varios projetos, o que nao intendi é funcionar no windows e nao funcionar no Mac OS

Comment: O MacOS já vem com Python instalado, porém é o 2.7.
A biblioteca que você está usando especifica que ela só funciona no Python 3.6+.
Você precisa instalar o python3 na máquina e usar `pip3 install requests-html` para utilizar a versão correta do Python.

Comment: Vale resaltar que instalei o python 3.7.1 e a versao do pip 18.0, estes testes foram feitos depois da instalacao

Comment: Novamente... Troque a imagem por textos e as pessoas vão identifcar imeditiamente que se trata da versão do python, faça um teste, instale o anaconda (ou o miniconda se preferir algo "enxuto", sem os pacotes cientificos) crie um venv com o python acima do python 3.6 e tente instalar via `conda` ou até mesmo via `pip`, pronto seu problema estará resolvido.